# Get a collection of listviewItem.Tags from ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection

Tags: vb.net, listview

Within a `listview` I have a number of checked items. I would like to get the tags for all checked items.

I have managed to do this by looping through each `listviewItem` and adding the `.Tag` to a collection but I feel that there must be a more efficient way to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share some code for a bit of discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
    Dim SelectedTags = From lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.CheckedItems Select lvi.Tag

    For Each SelectedTag In SelectedTags
        Debug.Print(SelectedTag)
    Next
```